# Notation: Meaning of brackets with subscript?

Tags: notation, cryptography

I came across the following expression: $[m + 2r + 2\sum_{i \in S}{x_i}]_{x_0}$. What does the subscripted bracket notation mean?

Context:
Found in this paper https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf.
Page 6, Section 3.1, in description of "Encrypt" function.

Comment: Can you give some context, i.e. where you found this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In section 2, the paper gives this definition:

[image]